# org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

various things result in this error, so I thought an answer to point this out would be useful, because the existing answers for this error were not helpful in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem

org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

how to diagnose (in android studio 3.2.1)

click on Build tab on bottom toolbar
click on Build tab (next to Sync tab) at the top of the panel that appears

you will see this:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> More details/hints about your problem here.
```

also add compile flags: go to File->Settings... -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Compiler -> Command-line Options: --stacktrace --info

click apply, ok

how to fix

in my case, it could not find the ndk, so I defined the environment variables

```
ANDROID_NDK
ANDROID_NDK_HOME
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT
```

all pointing to

```
d:\android\android-ndk-r18b
```

(the root of the ndk where it unzipped)

then, restart android studio (to see the new environment variables)
reload the project

File->Project Structure
set Android NDK location to same path as above, click OK

File->Sync Project with Gradle Files (or click Sync Project with Gradle Files icon in top toolbar)

now build and run work

if run is not available, need to Edit Configurations... in the dropdown next to the build hammer in android studio;
do another sync as shown above, then build and run work

Comment: I didn't realize the NDK wasn't fully installed with the default Android Studio. That gave me that problem configuring project ':app' as well despite it being a baseline project template Android Studio provides. That Project Structure tip you give above had pointed to a default folder which had a readme which ultimately linked me to https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides#download-ndk

Comment: actually I'm mistaken, it is installed, that link is for side by side installations for multiple NDK versions to be installed.